# How to Place two Text Form Fields side by side in flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, dart

I am trying to create a form in flutter. In which I want to keep the two text fields side by side as shown below:

[image: Sample Image]

I want to place **Department** and **Year of Study** field in same row as shown in picture. I am unable to do it. I have tried this using `Row` widget as shown below:

```
        Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
                    child: Text(
                      "Department",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontFamily: "Poppins",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
                    child: Text(
                      "Year of Study",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontFamily: "Poppins",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

However, its giving me error. On searching the google I have got some idea to wrap `TextFormField` in `Flexible()` widget but that also didn't worked for me and giving me a different type of error. I have also tried to wrap in `Expanded()` but the error is still coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code as per your above image show.

```
 Column(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Full Name'),
            subtitle: TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                hintText: 'Full Name',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListTile(
            title: Text('Department'),
            subtitle: TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                    hintText: '  Department',
                  ),
                ),),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child:ListTile(
            title: Text('Year Of Study'),
            subtitle:  TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                    hintText: '  Year Of Study',
                  ),
                ),),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Here the width of both the fields Department and Year Of Study will be equal i.e. they will be equally disrtibuted in the given width. Is there any way to increase width of one field and decrease the other one?

Comment: @enggPS, Yes set `flex property` to widget `Expanded(flex:4)` , `Expanded(flex:2)`  change flex on your need refer [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) or You can used Expanded as Well as Flexible also, refer [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each of them in sized boxed and give them a fixed width. The problem is because Rows and TextFormFields expand infinitely. And when putting a textformfield inside a row, you'll get a renderflex error. A sized box would solve this by giving it a limited width.

Comment: I got this idea. But wrapping the fields inside ListTile seems to be a better option for me.

Comment: List tiles would also work, but those also need to have a bound width, not infinty.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the childrens into Expanded Widget:

```
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 5),
                child: Text(
                  "Department",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 8),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 5),
                child: Text(
                  "Year of Study",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

I also added a **SizedBox** in between, the **flex property** to have different sizes for the text fields and the **crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start** to have the text on the left side.